# Comparing Geographic datatypes in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Currently I am working on generating demographics of a database and we have added `geography` datatype in one of the tables. For demographics I have to produce *max, min and avg* of columns with other things.

Using

```
select MIN(Location) FROM SpatialTable
```

didn't work as geography datatype is incomparable.

So I used following query :

```
SELECT Location 
FROM SpatialTable 
WHERE Location.Lat IN (SELECT MIN(Location.Lat) 
                       FROM SpatialTable 
                       WHERE Location.Long IN (SELECT MIN(Location.Long) 
                                               FROM SpatialTable))
```

which basically selects the records with minimum Longitudes and then among those records it selects the one with minimum Latitude. But this can also be done other way round in which first MIN latitude is selected and among them MIN longitude is selected, like this:

```
SELECT 
    Location 
FROM 
    SpatialTable 
WHERE 
    Location.Long IN
        (SELECT MIN(Location.Long) 
         FROM SpatialTable 
         WHERE Location.Lat IN (SELECT MIN(Location.Lat) FROM SpatialTable))
```

which may produce different result.

Is there a precise way to compare geographic data. I am using SQL Server 2008 R2 edition and my table has one Location column of geography type and an identity column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To determine the minimum of a geography type, first you have to define what you mean by minimum. What is the minimum of a geography? It's like asking

> what is the minimum of a dog?

How can one geography be less or more than another? Is London less than Paris*? Answer this, and you'll have your answer. At a guess, I'd say your answer may be the `STDistance` function.

*No, it's greater. Any fule knows that

Comment: Well I was hoping if there is an universally accepted way to compare geo data like neg nos < pos nos is universally accepted. I have defined my comparing criteria in which MIN = (-90, -90) and MAX = (90, 90) viz. (LAT, LONG) but this is not universally accepted and there is a possibilty of ambiguity in future.

Comment: In that case, use STDistance with reference to -90 -90 : ie: `location.STDistance(geography::STGeomFromText('POINT(-90 -90)', 4326))`

Answer (score 0):

Irrelevant to geography, you can use [`ROW_NUMBER()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function to get row with min(or max) value on custom criteria.

```
SELECT x.* FROM 
(
    SELECT *
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Location.Lat, Location.Long) RN
    FROM SpatialTable
) x
WHERE x.RN = 1
```